# Can Kindle's dictionary be disabled?

Tags: kindle, dictionaries

I find Kindle's dictionary feature to be annoying - I've used Touch and Paperwhite, where I'm touching the screen all the time, and I frequently get an annoying pop-up definition I don't want.

Is there any way to disable the dictionary?

Answer (score 5):

I think the only option you have is to delete the dictionary completely, thus disabling it. (Search for the dictionary on your device and remove it like any other book. You can re-download it later if there is the need.)

Comment: This was my first attempt. But then I _still_ get the pop-up, with the message: `There are no dictionaries on your device. To download a dictionary...` Gah.

Comment: I don't see how to do this. Maybe they removed this option.